# How to change the background color of navigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the background color of the navigation bar to black but without success.  I have checked the answer to this related question but none of the solutions have worked.  This is what I have tried:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: have you checked this..?? self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change the navigation bar color for a specific view controller, this way:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setCustomNavigationColor(color: UIColor = .black, isTranslucent: Bool = false ){
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = isTranslucent
    }
}
```

call this from *viewDidLoad()*

```
setCustomNavigationColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Note: This changes the bar colour for the entire app.

Comment: I've updated, check if you are putting this code somewhere that is getting executed.

Comment: The code is placed in viewDidLoad(). I don't really get it.  the updated answer still will not get my navigationBar black.

Comment: Place it in `applicationDidFinishLaunch` inside `AppDelegate`